# Should the duplicate question close reason text be changed?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

Currently, we close questions as duplicates if either the question has been asked before, OR the answer to the new question has been addressed before.

The text when closing a question as a duplicate is:

> This question has been asked before and has an answer.

The text displayed when a question has been marked as a duplicate is:

> This question already has an answer here:

But these aren't necessarily true. The question may have been asked before, but never received an answer. (Note: I haven't checked the data explorer, so this may be an edge case, but it's still a possibility for a cause of confusion.)

Comment: I believe as part of the close reason changes, there was logic added that prevented a question from being marked as dupe of a question that has no answers.

Comment: @Keen I didn't go through with the vote, but I tried setting my Maleficent question as an original for a dupe and didn't get an error.

Comment: I expect it blocks the actual vote. I haven't seen it in action myself, but I read about it several times on MSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried to close a question as a dupe, but as the original question did not have any answers, much less an accepted or upvoted answer, I received the following message:

> **This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer**

and I could not vote to close.

So, the message will always be correct and does not need to be changed.

(Though, I feel like we should still be able to mark dupes regardless of whether or not there is an existing answer.)

Comment: there is an exception if the answerless question is by the same user but this is generally correct.